# Get CheckBox default Drawable in versions <Android M

Tags: java, android

I want t**o omit the default padding of Android CheckBox**. So , that customized CheckBox as below.

But it will work only versions >= Android M.

How can I **get default drawable of CheckBox in versions < Android M**

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int w=40;
        int h=40;
        setMeasuredDimension(w,h);
        //super.onMeasure(w, h);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable drawable= null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            drawable = getButtonDrawable();
        }
        drawable.setBounds(-15,-15,55,55);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Comment: I found this, may be helpful to you : https://github.com/UBERROMS/frameworks_support/blob/master/compat/java/android/support/v4/widget/CompoundButtonCompat.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method,

```
Drawable drawable = CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(this);
```

You can refer the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CompoundButtonCompat.html#getButtonDrawable(android.widget.CompoundButton)) and let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: Super Answer brother. (Y)